Proof of a special case of Cauchy's theorem on finite abelian groups
I am self-studying abstract algebra from the book by Thomas Judson, which the author freely made available online.
Talking about the structure of finite Abelian groups, the author wants to prove the following lemma:
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. If $p$ is a prime that divides $n$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.
I am confused about a point in the proof. The author uses induction and, while assuming that the lemma holds for all groups of order $k<n$, he writes:

Now suppose that $G$ contains a nontrivial proper subgroup H. Then $1<|H|<n$. If $p | |H|$, then $H$ contains an element of order $p$ by induction and the lemma is true.
Suppose that $p$ does not divide the order of $H$. Since $G$ is abelian, it must be the case that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $|G| = |H|\cdot |G/H|$. Consequently, $p$ must divide $|G/H|$. Since $|G/H| < |G| = n$, we know that $G/H$ contains an element $aH$ of order $p$ by the induction hypothesis. Thus,
$$
H = (aH)^p = a^pH
$$
and $a^p\in H$, but $a\notin H$.

I understand why $a^p\in H$, but why $a$ doesn't belong to $H$?
Notice that the author uses this lemma to then prove the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups. Therefore I cannot use that theorem to prove the lemma.
I think that if I can say that $a^p$ is the identity and $a\in H$, then I can consider the cyclic group $<a>\subset H$. Now, since $a^p=e$ and $p$ is prime, then $|<a>|=p$. By the Lagrange theorem $p$ must then divide the order of $H$, but we are under the hypothesis that $p$ doesn't divide $|H|$. So $a\notin H$.
Am I on the correct way? And if yes, why $a^p$ must be the identity?

This is a duplicate. Please use the search feature if this site.

@MartinBrandenburg I don't think it is a duplicate, because Lukas is asking for an explanation about a particular step of the proof.

Yes but these steps have been explained in the duplicates. By the way you are answering questions in the comments which is against the site policy as you know.

@MartinBrandenburg, I did use the search function of the website and I also looked at some suggestions that appeared while I was writing the answer. The closer questions were https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888310/proof-of-cauchys-theorem-for-abelian-groups and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889382/clarification-of-proof-of-cauchys-theorem-for-abelian-groups but they do not really answer the step in my specific question. If you have a post in mind, I will be happy to edit my answer and add a reference to it.

Since $aH\in G/H$ is of order $p>1$, it is not equal to the identity element $H$ of $G/H$. Now, $aH\ne H\iff a\notin H$.

If this answer is truly a duplicate, I will be happy and delete it.
